# handling date for a mobile app using firebase as backend

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

my question is not specific to firebase and i think applicable in general.

In my case, the mobile app (a hybrid app) runs in india and the backend is firebase using nodejs. It is a food ordering app.

When a person orders the food, we use (new Date()).getTime() in the mobile app and pass that as order date.

Every time when an order is placed, a firebase trigger updates the total day sale till that time in JSON realtime DB object. And to save the total sale we use beginning of the day as the date-time timestamp. it's calculated using:

```
 var date = new Date()
 var ms = date.getTime();
 var msPerDay = 86400 * 1000;
 var timestamp =   ms - (ms % msPerDay);
```

I think this whole thing is already a mess as new Date() will give different values in the mobile app in india and on firebase server (running in US north) at the same moment.

So, what is the practice to handle dates in my situation?

Comment: "*new Date() will give different values in the mobile app in India and on firebase server (running in US north)*" if the clocks are synchronised, they will not. Dates are UTC, always. When you do `ms - (ms % msPerDay)` that is the equivalent of `date.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)`. If your offset is +0530, then `date.toString()` will show 05:30 am, i.e. your local time when UTC is midnight.

Comment: so u r saying i just  dont need to worry at all i am doing above is just correct? in other words, when mobile app passes (new Date()).getTime() that will be same value as firebase doing at the same time (new Date()).getTime() ?

Comment: Yes, provided the clock is accurate (which is certainly not guaranteed).

Answer (score 2):

When `new Date()` is executed, a *Date* instance is created with a time value that represents the current time UTC.

For hosts where the clock is accurate and the timezone setting correct, Dates created at the same moment will have the time value regardless of where the host is or its timezone setting. However, in the age of "the internet of things", the host may be any one of a huge array of devices where the clock and settings may be anything but accurate.

So you really should not rely on the client being accurate and use server times for things that matter.

When you do:

```
var date = new Date()
var ms = date.getTime();
var msPerDay = 86400 * 1000;
var timestamp =   ms - (ms % msPerDay);
```

you're setting the time to the start of the UTC day. It's equivalent to:

```
var timestamp = new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
```

For 2018-11-02, that will be: 1541116800000.

You can store that if you like, but maybe you want to store it as a human readable date, in which case:

```
var timestamp = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10); // 2018-11-02 on 2 Nov 2018
```

may suit, but it's generally recommended to use a full string, so:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
var timestamp = d.toISOString(); // 2018-11-02T00:00:00Z on 2 Nov 2018
```

Note that the UTC date is different to the local date for the period of the local timezone offset (so from midnight to 05:30 local time in India will show yesterday's date).

```js
console.log(
  new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)).toISOString()
);
```

Comment: ok so let's say i am storing it as (new Date()).getTime()  now when i retrieve it on client side:  should  new Date(timestamp stored on server) is ok or does this need to be different?  also when i print  above date.getMonth() that prints 11 but date.getUtcMonth() prints 12 . why

Comment: The UTC month will vary from the local month for the period of the host timezone offset from midnight on the first of the month for time zones with positive offsets, and on the last day of the month for time zones with negative offsets. At all other times the month will be the same. The maximum positive offset is +14, so after 2 pm on 1 November UTC everywhere has the same UTC and local month until the maximum negative offset of -12 on the last day of the month, so until noon on 30 November UTC.

Comment: So I should use get Month or get UTC month in the mobile app code

Comment: plz advise on this

Comment: `date.getUTCMonth()` will [never show 12](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#eqn-MonthFromTime). I can't tell you which method to use without knowing exactly what you're doing and how you're using dates, which is beyond the scope of this part of StackOverflow.